# iMac as external display for new MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, thunderbolt, displayport

I've got an iMac from [2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP689?viewlocale=en_US&locale=de_DE). Will I be able to use this as an external display for the new MacBook Pro? If yes, which adapters will I need? I'm not sure what to make of this info from [apples site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736) about the MacBook ports:

> The USB-C port on your Mac notebook supports charging, data transfer, and other modes such as DisplayPort video. You can use a USB-C adapter to connect to HDMI and VGA displays or connect other standard USB devices. This includes devices like iPhones, iPads, and iPods for charging and syncing, and cameras, hard drives, and thumb drives for transferring data.
>   The USB-C port on your Mac notebook doesn't support Thunderbolt devices or displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target display mode is supported on [your iMac](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP689) and how to use it is described in [this support document](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204592) on the Apple site.

It states that for the Mid 2011 iMac, which you linked to, a Thunderbolt cable will work (Thunderbolt wraps the DisplayPort data stream)

> `iMacs you can use | Cable       | Port you need`
>   `as a display      | you need    | on your other Mac`
>   `----------------------------------------------------`
>   `iMac (Mid 2011)   | Thunderbolt | Thunderbolt`
>
> ### Use Target Display Mode
>
> Follow these steps to start using your iMac as a display:
>    1. Make sure both computers are turned on.
>    2. Connect the Mini DisplayPort or
>   Thunderbolt cable between the two computers.
>    3. Press `Command-F2` on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.
>
> After you press `Command-F2`, your iMac displays the desktop from
>   the connected Mac.

So, you should be able to connect a new MacBook Pro via a [Thunderbolt 3 -> Thunderbolt 2 adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) and a [standard Thunderbolt 2 cable](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m).